# Python Threading - Simple but tricky

Tags: python, multithreading

Could someone please point out, why my code is not printing "hello". I feel that my thread 2 - t2 is not starting. This is just a code snippet, I am trying to work on to implement in my main program. Basically, my idea is the following:

1. Have a single function - which has two set of codes ---- one code in "if condition statement" and the other in "while loop"
2. Thread 1 - uses function 1 - "while loop" continuously - until I abruptly stop the program
3. Thread 2 or thread 3 or thread 4 etc, wants to use the same function - but the code under "if condition statement"
4. My approach in the following code is to have a thread 1 - run continuously, while thread2 - does its work without interrupting thread1.

The code:

```
import threading
import Queue



def Continuous(stop_event, queue_read, queue_write,lock):

    #lock.acquire()
    try:

        if stop_event == True:

            print stop_event.is_set()
            print "hello"
            c = 7
            d = 8
            msg2 = (c+d)*2
            queue_write.put(msg2)

        while not stop_event.wait(1):
            print "hello2"
            #print ("working on %s" % arg)
            a = 3;
            b = 4
            msg1 = a*b
            queue_read.put(msg1)
            time.sleep(1)

    finally:
        print "Inside finally"
        #lock.release()

    print"Outside try and finally"




def main():

    pill2kill = threading.Event()
    lock = threading.Lock()

    pill2kill.clear()
    queue1 = Queue.Queue()
    queue2 = Queue.Queue()
    #self.queue2 = Queue.Queue()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = Continuous, args = (pill2kill,queue1,queue2,lock))
    t1.deamon = True
    t1.start()

    print "asdfasfd"
    time.sleep(2)
    pill2kill_1 = threading.Event()
    pill2kill_1.set()
    print "hjgkhj"
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=Continuous, args=(pill2kill_1, queue1, queue2,lock))
    t2.start()
    t2.join()
    pill2kill.clear()
    print "End of program"


main()
```

PS: I am extremely sorry, for posting my code this way. I tried for over 15 minutes and I am unsuccesful to get it formatted

Comment: What is your question? Or error?

Comment: Weird, I'm trying to edit it and the formatting doesn't work...

Comment: @Jezor that might be because the code follows a bullet list without any other normal body text elements in between. Usually inserting an empty HTML comment `<!-- -->` between two elements like these does the trick.

Comment: My question is why does my thread2 - t2 does not start and print "hello"

Comment: FYI, `t1.deamon = True` does nothing; the attribute is spelled `daemon`.  Also, `if stop_event == True:` will always fail (`stop_event` is an `Event`, it's not equal to anything of type `bool`, did you mean `if stop_event.is_set():`?). Finally, you set the event for the second thread before you start, so `while not stop_event.wait(1):` will exit the loop immediately; the only expected output would be from the `finally` block and below the `finally`.

Answer (score 0):

(Converted from comment because subsequent comment by OP made it clear what they were expecting) The problems come from misuse of `Event`:

1. `if stop_event == True:` will always evaluate to `False` and the `if` block never executes its contents (`stop_event` is an `Event`, it's not equal to anything of type `bool`, did you mean `if stop_event.is_set():`?). This prevents `hello` from being printed.
2. You set the event for the second thread before you create the thread, let alone start it, so `while not stop_event.wait(1):` will exit the loop immediately without executing the body (preventing `hello2` from being printed); the only expected output would be from the `finally` block and below the `finally`.

Side-note: `t1.deamon = True` does nothing; the attribute is spelled `daemon`. Since you never `set` the `Event` for thread 1, this seems like it would mean the program would never exit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any way that I could use the lock, if so where would you suggest putting it? Definitely the locations where I put in currently wont suffice my requirement

Comment: @JeshKundem: I have literally no idea what you intend the lock to be used for. I mean, you could use a single lock to lock all uses of `print` (in all threads) so you don't get interleaved output, but otherwise, most of your work is intrinsically thread safe (`Queue`s are self-locking, `Event`s are thread-safe, etc.), purely local use of immutable types is safe, etc. Your problems are mostly in how you use `Event`s on an API level, not a thread safety issue.